# "Sure" as an adverb

Tags: word-usage

> [Sure](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=sure&oq=sure&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.831j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=define:%20sure) (adverb) [NORTH AMERICAN] [informal] - certainly (used for emphasis).
>
> Example : "Texas sure was a great place to grow up."

- I thought using *sure* as an emphatic adverb is grammatical, I saw it very often. But the dictionary says that it is **informal**, so using it like that in a test is not okay, right?
- `"Texas was sure a great place to grow up."` Can "sure" be sued *after* the helping verb? Will it cause confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context of the test and the quote.  If you are quoting someone who is of an informal nature (local Texan) saying something like:

"Texas sure was a great place to grow up"

The grammatically correct usage would be not to use the word "sure" at all.  Again, it depends on the context.  If the subject of the quote was talking to someone about how good Texas was, it can be used like:

"Surely Texas was a great place to grow up.... you had big spaces to play in and great weather..."

Comment: Please don't confuse formality with grammatical correctness.